# Access RDS (Mysql) database from two autoscaled instances in different regions (USWest and Singapore)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

My requirement was access one RDS database to different instances in different regions for latency.

Can you guys help me in that or give me another way how I need to do that ?

Comment: Just check Amazon RDS Security Groups lah

Comment: In security groups we have added same region IP's, but I need to access RDS from another region instance...

Comment: Have you tried adding public IP address of your EC Instance to RDS security group? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102827